# (Swift) how to print "\" character in a string?

Tags: ios, swift, string, escaping, slash

I have tried to print it but it just by passes because it's an escaped character.
e.g output should be as follows.

```
\correct
```

Comment: Escape it again with another backslash: `"ab\\cd"` will give `"ab\cd"`

Comment: It *is documented* in the Swift Book, and a link to the relevant chapter was provided in a comment to your previous question.

Comment: Don't know why this question got those negative feedback, because it definitely helped me. The problem is, double backslash doesn't get shown in right panel when in playground

Answer (score 66, accepted):

For that and also future reference:

```
\0 – Null character (that is a zero after the slash)
\\ – Backslash itself.  Since the backslash is used to escape other characters, it needs a special escape to actually print itself.
\t  – Horizontal tab
\n – Line Feed
\r  – Carriage Return
\”  – Double quote.  Since the quotes denote a String literal, this is necessary if you actually want to print one.
\’  – Single Quote.  Similar reason to above.
```

Comment: Why does a single-quote need to be escaped, anyway?

Comment: @DuncanC because compiler can't decide whether it is end of the string or a double slash IN the string

Comment: in swift 4 "\\" gives you "\\"

Comment: how to print apostrophe in swift ?

Answer (score 20):

Use the following code for **Swift 5, Xcode 10.2**

```
let myText = #"This is a Backslash: \"#
print(myText)
```

**Output:**

> This is a Backslash: \

Now not required to add a double slash to use a single slash in swift 5, even now required slash before some character, for example, single quote, double quote etc.

See this post for latest update about swift 5

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/126/whats-new-in-swift-5-0

Comment: Trying this on Swift 5, Xcode 11.1 is printing out: " This is a Backslash: \\ "

Comment: I'm using Swift 5.1 and it's working perfectly for me. Idk for sure about Swift 5, but I'm sure it works for Swift 5.1.

Answer (score 6):

```swift
var s1: String = "I love my "
let s2: String = "country"
s1 += "\"\(s2)\""
print(s1)
```

It will print I love my "country"

Answer (score 5):

The backslash character `\` acts as an escape character when used in a string. This means you can use, for example, double quotes, in a string by pre-pending them with `\`. The same also applies for the backslash character itself, which is to say that `println("\\")` will result in just `\` being printed.

Comment: Thanks for the education, Eric, and sorry for such a noob mistake.  I had been relying on Playground's output on the right, and never once have used that bottom panel.  The lightbulb has now been lit.  You must be a mod?  I started another thread on this topic and it should probably die also.